# Prove that if $A$ is invertible and $B\neq0$ then $AB\neq0$ using null space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Prove that if $A_{3\times3}$ is invertible and $B_{3\times3}\neq0$ then $AB\neq0$.

I'm aware that there're simpler proofs but I was wondering if this one is correct.

Suppose that $AB=0$ then every column $\underline b_i$ of $B$ is the solution to the system $A \underline x=\underline 0$. This means  that $\{\underline b_1,\underline b_2, \underline b_3\}\subseteq$ null space of $A$.

But $A$ is invertible therefore its null space is only the zero vector hence:
$$
\{\underline b_1,\underline b_2,\underline b_3\}\subseteq\{\underline 0\}\Rightarrow B=\underline 0
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is correct, I apologize.

Comment: Easier: if $A$ is invertible and $AB=0$, then also $B=A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}0=0$. In your style, without contradiction: let $Bx\ne0$; then $ABx\ne0$, because $Bx$ doesn't belong to the null space of $A$.

Comment: @egreg The OP wanted to know if his proof was correct, not *how* to prove the statement.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's why I wrote a comment, rather than an answer. What about upvoting the question? You definitely should, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. I don't understand why you wrote $\underline0$ instead of just writing $0$, though.

Comment: I wanted to show that it's the zero vector not just zero.

Comment: @Yos But you wrote $B=0$, and $B$ is no number either.

Comment: $B$ is the matrix so I think capital letters are usually used for matrices. I think you do have a point regarding ${b_1..b_2}$ though. I'll edit that